# What are possible reasons the html5 video tag works for some users but not others?

Tags: 2013, video

The OS for the users range from Win 7 to Win 8.1. Browser is ie11.  Always works right for admin users no matter what machine.  Works for 1 regular user no matter what machine.  Fails for all other users no matter what machine.  Video lives on a media server. SharePoint is 2013.

I can open ie as admin and another browser window on the same machine as a regular user and have them side by side and the admin user will see the video and the regular user will get an error or see nothing.

Comment: What does the error say? How is the video displayed on the page? Webpart? :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of reasons that I can think of the top of my head:

1) Page not checked-in/published

2) Access to video not available to other users ( check permissions on media server)

3) If its a custom webpart, then probably the script/partial is not checked in/published (most likely the associated html or js files are not checked-in/published).

Since you mentioned that admin is able to view the video, this looks most likely to be a permission issue. Inspect the console (press F12, click on console tab) and check for errors. There could be couple of 403 Forbidden errors. Find out the individual files(components) that are used in playing the video and publish them or make them accessible to users without permission.

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s).  I confirmed the page is checked in. I checked the media server and the group "everyone" that includes the entire company has read and execute rights on the mp4 file.

Comment: The edit function for my prior comment won't submit my changes so here is the second half.

The console (f12) shows no errors.  In a web part the space is there for the video but the video can't be played.  When the web part is replaced with a page viewer and the video tag is on that page the "error; Media playback was aborted" shows on the box for the video along with a black background. A search on that error returned info on codex and video screen size. Neither applies in this case.